# How do I display sum of ng-repeat elements on their change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a `ng-repeat` generated set of `<Select>` which contain a numerical value. I want their overall numerical sum to be displayed whenever one `<Select>` is changed by the user. `{{option.score}}` represents the numerical value I wish to allot into a total.

**Image:**

https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/NGg0gJn.png

**Template:**

```
    <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-repeat="criteria in tool.criterias">
        <div class="input-label">
            {{criteria.desc}}
        </div>
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="option in criteria.options">
                {{option.score}} &mdash; {{option.answer}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </label>
    ...
    <p>Total: the sum of all the option.score's</p>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('FullToolsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Tools) {
  $scope.tool = Tools.get($stateParams.toolId);
});
```

**Data:**

```
{
  "criterias": [
    {
      "desc": "Complexion",
      "options": [
        {
          "answer": "Blue or Pale all over",
          "score": "0"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Blue at extremities",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "answer": "No cyanosed body or extremities",
          "score": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "desc": "Pulse",
      "options": [
        {
          "answer": "Absent",
          "score": "0"
        },
        {
          "answer": "< 100",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "answer": "> 100",
          "score": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "desc": "Grimace",
      "options": [
        {
          "answer": "No response to stimulation",
          "score": "0"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Grimace on suction or aggressive stimulation",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Cry on stimulation",
          "score": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "desc": "Activity",
      "options": [
        {
          "answer": "Absent",
          "score": "0"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Some flexion",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Flexed arms and legs resist extension",
          "score": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "desc": "Respiratory effort",
      "options": [
        {
          "answer": "Absent",
          "score": "0"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Weak, irregular, gasping",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "answer": "Strong, lusty cry",
          "score": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "desc": "Scoring tool for neonates.",
  "name": "APGAR Score"
}
```

Comment: can you describe a little more or perhaps a jsfiddle link? what is bind in the select tag and what you want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with data set. The JSON data goes to build the view. I want it so the numbers represented in each select are added up and totaled which is displayed on the page (in the last <p>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
  $scope.total = 0;
  $scope.selectValue = [];
  $scope.SumValue = function() {
    $scope.total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectValue.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.selectValue[i] != undefined)
        $scope.total += parseInt($scope.selectValue[i]);
    }

  }
  $scope.data = {
    "criterias": [{
      "desc": "Complexion",
      "options": [{
        "answer": "Blue or Pale all over",
        "score": "0"
      }, {
        "answer": "Blue at extremities",
        "score": "1"
      }, {
        "answer": "No cyanosed body or extremities",
        "score": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "desc": "Pulse",
      "options": [{
        "answer": "Absent",
        "score": "0"
      }, {
        "answer": "< 100",
        "score": "1"
      }, {
        "answer": "> 100",
        "score": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "desc": "Grimace",
      "options": [{
        "answer": "No response to stimulation",
        "score": "0"
      }, {
        "answer": "Grimace on suction or aggressive stimulation",
        "score": "1"
      }, {
        "answer": "Cry on stimulation",
        "score": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "desc": "Activity",
      "options": [{
        "answer": "Absent",
        "score": "0"
      }, {
        "answer": "Some flexion",
        "score": "1"
      }, {
        "answer": "Flexed arms and legs resist extension",
        "score": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "desc": "Respiratory effort",
      "options": [{
        "answer": "Absent",
        "score": "0"
      }, {
        "answer": "Weak, irregular, gasping",
        "score": "1"
      }, {
        "answer": "Strong, lusty cry",
        "score": "2"
      }]
    }],
    "desc": "Scoring tool for neonates.",
    "name": "APGAR Score"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-repeat="criteria in data.criterias">
      <label>
        {{ criteria.desc }}
      </label>
      <br/>
      <select ng-model="selectValue[$index]" ng-change="SumValue()">
        <option ng-repeat="option in criteria.options" value="{{option.score}}">{{option.answer}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p>Total: the sum of all the option.score's {{ total }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d42jeuvs/15/

Hope this is what you wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time writing this Sk. Tajbir. - However this demo continues to add when instead it should re-evaluate the total from all the select. For example if you keep changing a value the total will raise above the maximum of 10. - Essentially the total should always be between 0 and 10 and be evaluated from the present values of all the select.

Comment: You can write you own custom logic in SumValue function. Also you can send your desired value in the function as well. Let me know whether that will help you or not. Thanks.

Comment: I've changed the above code and jsfiddle. I think this is what you wanted to achieve. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Sk. Tajbir. I was working on a similar solution but you beat me to it. Interesting to know $scope.selectValue would be an array but that makes sense now. I had looked at using $index in the past but had marked it on the `<option>` element.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really built into ng-repeat to deal with this and you're actually outside of the ng-repeat construct when you want your total to appear. Generally you would just bind an expression in your HTML to a function call in your controller. Something like:

```
<p>Total: the sum of all the option.score's  {{total)()}}</p>
```

(where $ctrl is your controller).

Then in your controller you'd have a function mapped to it with something like:

$scope.total = function() {
     var total = 0
     angular.forEach($scope. criteria.options, function(criteria) {
        total+= criteria.score
     }
     return total
};

If you're using controllerAs syntax it'd be slighltly different.

Comment: What did you mean by $ctrl is your controller?